# Fixed menu doesn't work properly, disturb the fluency of the page

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I've developed a Wordpress menu, this menu should change when you scroll down and should become a different menu. Everything works fine in the menu but I'm not getting why every time that the menu change from "relative" to fixed I lose a piece of page and this is very annoying.

This is the website with the menu:
http://matrix-test.com/scoilbhride/

as you can see when you scroll down and the menu changes I'm automatically brought at the mid of the slide. It is not very functional in this way and not fluent.

Here my html:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <nav>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <?php happylearning_header_logo() ?>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-toggle-main">
            <span>MENU</span>
        </div>
  <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array( 

            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'container' => 'nav',
            'container_class' => 'nav-bar-conatainer',
            'menu_class' => 'menu-class'

            ) );
  ?>
    </nav>
</div>
```

There is a Wordpress function instead of the nav container, the ul and li.

so something like this:

```
<nav class="nav-bar-conatainer">
   <ul class="menu-class">
       <li><a>example</a></li>
       <li><a>example</a></li>
       <li><a>example</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Here my css:

```
.nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #577188;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}

.main-navbar-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.site-logo {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 20;
}

.site-logo > a.site-logo__link > img.site-link__img {
    max-width: 190px;
}

.logo-navbar-fixed {
    max-width: 125px !important;
}

nav.nav-bar-conatainer {
    text-align: right;
}

ul.menu-class {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 190px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.menu-class > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.menu-class > li.current-menu-item {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

ul.menu-class > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.menu-class > li > a:hover {
    color: #c7d13e;
}

#menu-menu_website > li > ul.sub-menu  {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #7e9cb9;
}

#menu-menu_website > li:last-child > ul.sub-menu {
    right: 0px;
}

#menu-menu_website > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#menu-menu_website > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
}

#menu-menu_website > li > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu-menu_website > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #c7d13e;
}

#menu-toggle-main {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#menu-toggle-main > span {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.active-main-menu {
    display: block !important;
}

.margin-from-header {
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.bkg-img-subpages {
    min-height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Here my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the
      //nav bar to stick.
      console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop())
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 180) {
      jQuery('.nav-wrap').addClass('main-navbar-fixed');
    }
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 181) {
      jQuery('.nav-wrap').removeClass('main-navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the
      //nav bar to stick.
      console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop())
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 180) {
      jQuery('.site-link__img').addClass('logo-navbar-fixed');
    }
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 181) {
      jQuery('.site-link__img').removeClass('logo-navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's because the first header takes up space on the page, the fixed one doesn't so the content jumps up. I'd suggest (Probably not the best) to make your original header position absolute and have a padding-top on the first content.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested

```
.site-content-wrap {padding-top: 194px}
header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Your main header takes up space where the fixed one does not. So when the main header disappears, so does the space it took up.